# sml suppress warnings for intentionally nonexhaustive pattern matching

Tags: sml

Suppose I have a datatype like:

```
datatype location = Safe of string | Dangerous of string * int;
```

And in this hypothetical example, I want to write a function that will only ever be passed a `Safe str` and never a `Dangerous(str, num)`:

```
fun send_kids (Safe address) = ...
```

Is there any way to suppress the warnings? Tell SML I *know* tis nonexhaustive?

```
stdIn:1.6-1.29 Warning: match nonexhaustive
          Safe s => ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. You "tell" SML by making it exhaustive with a failure case:

```
fun sendKinds (Safe address) = ...
  | sendKinds _ = raise Fail "sendKinds"
```